# How to add uri segment as parameter into a function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I will try to illustrate what I am trying to do :

I want my url's like :

```
www.mysite.com/abc-university
              /def-university
              /fde-university
```

Before "-university" is the name of university. All my segment(1) ends with university.

I have a class called `University`.In it; there is `get_university()` function.

In routes.php, I wrote:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "university/get_university";
```

Here is what my class looks like:

```
class University extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('university_model');
  }

  function get_university($university_segment){

    $query = $this->university_model->get_from_university($university_segment);

    $row = $query->row();

    echo "Welcome to " . $row->university_name . "page";                

   } 
}
```

`$university_segment` is "/abc_university.

I want to take segment-1(abc_university) into `get_university($university_segment)` function as parameter and fetch information from database according to that university.

I tried even `_remap()` function but I couldn't. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_university(){
$university_segment=$this->uri->segment(1);
$query = $this->university_model->get_from_university($university_segment);

$row = $query->row();

echo "Welcome to " . $row->university_name . "page";                

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is true. Also I become succesful using both _remap and uri routing like : function _remap($university_segment){
       
        $this->get_university($university_segment); Thank you.. Both work.